# How to take the mode across elements in multiple numpy arrays of 1-d

Tags: python, numpy, element

I am able to take the sum across multiple lists/arrays element-by-element, as per

```
sum([np.array([1,2,3,4,5]), np.array([1,2,3,4,5])]) = array([ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10])
```

I want to do something similar for the mode off each element across arrays, with expected results:

`mode([np.array([1,2,3,4,5]), np.array([1,2,3,4,5])]) = array([ 1,  2,  3,  4, 5]`)

In the case where there is no single mode, then I would like to select the element in one of the arrays, randomly,  for the output, as per:

`mode([np.array([0,2,3,4,0]), np.array([1,2,9,4,5])]) = array([ 1,  2,  9,  4, 0]`)

lastly, I would like to be able to do this operation across an arbitrary number of arrays of equal length.

NB: I tried using the stats library mode, and got the following error:

```
>>> mode([np.array([1,2,3,4,5]), np.array([1,2,3,4,5])])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/statistics.py", line 501, in mode
    table = _counts(data)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/statistics.py", line 252, in _counts
    table = collections.Counter(iter(data)).most_common()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/collections/__init__.py", line 566, in __init__
    self.update(*args, **kwds)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/collections/__init__.py", line 653, in update
    _count_elements(self, iterable)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

It also throws an error when using just a list.

I am thus looking for a way to achieve this.

A key requirement is that the output vector of modes across array elements has to be the same length as each vector (I will be feeding it into a confusion matrix to do a comparison against a reference vector).

Comment: You can use [`scipy.stats.mode`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html)

Comment: I tried. I'll post the error I get. Also, even if it were tto work, how would I handle the case with no mode?

Comment: You will have to post a minimal, reproducible example and explain what goes wrong. Post some code that others can run without changing anything.

Comment: Thanks! I did, and I gave the expected results.

Comment: `sum` works because arrays add, `arr1+arr2`.  `mode` is defined for numbers, and does not do any sort of object method deligation.

Comment: Right, which is why I am asking how I can achieve this.

Comment: The scipy mode makes a 2d array from your inputs, and iterates across the columns, determining the mode one column at a time. I suspect `[mode(args) for args in zip([arr1,arr2])]` would do just as well.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I'm not sure this actually returns the element-wise mode.

Comment: For `[scipy.stats.mode(args) for args in zip([np.array([0, 1, 2]),np.array([3, 4, 5])])]` , I get `[ModeResult(mode=array([[0, 1, 2]]), count=array([[1, 1, 1]])), ModeResult(mode=array([[3, 4, 5]]), count=array([[1, 1, 1]]))]`

Comment: My mistake, use `zip(arr1, arr2)` or `zip(*[arr1, arr2]))`.  We want the `zip` to iterate (in parallel) through the two arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the mode using `scipy.stats.mode`. You can also concatenate your multiple numpy arrays into a single array, and then feed that to mode.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats

arrays = [np.array([0,2,3,4,0]), np.array([1,2,9,4,5])]

result = scipy.stats.mode(np.concatenate(arrays))
# ModeResult(mode=array([0]), count=array([2]))

result.mode
# array([0])
```

The return value of `scipy.stats.mode` is a namedtuple `ModeResult`, which includes the mode and the number of times the value(s) appear.

To find the mode per column, you can stack your arrays into a 2D array, and then find the mode along the first axis.

```
arrays = [
    np.array([0, 2, 3, 4, 0]), 
    np.array([1, 2, 9, 4, 5]), 
    np.array([0, 9, 9, 4, 1])]
result = scipy.stats.mode(np.stack(arrays), axis=0)
result.mode
# array([[0, 2, 9, 4, 0]])
```

Comment: What version of scipy are you using? I'm not seeing this error in `scipy.__version__` 1.4.1. `scipy.stats.mode` returns the smallest number if multiple modes are found.

Comment: Not quite, I will add further requirements. Plus, this throws an error: `statistics.StatisticsError: no unique mode; found 3 equally common values`

Comment: Me bad! I was using the `mode` from the statistics library.

Comment: I can live with the smallest number being selected if multiple/no modes are found (instead of a random number, that is). The big requirement is that I am *not* taking the mode of the elements in the array, I am taking the mode between arrays, element-by-element. Otherwise, this is close. Any way to transpose this?

Comment: I think I understand. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

With your two examples:

```
In [358]: alist = [np.array([1,2,3,4,5]), np.array([1,2,3,4,5])]                        
In [359]: alist1 = [np.array([0,2,3,4,0]), np.array([1,2,9,4,5])]
```

Two sources:

```
In [360]: import statistics                                                             
In [361]: from scipy import stats
```

With `zip(*alist)` we can take the mode of corresponding 'pairs':

```
In [362]: [statistics.mode(foo) for foo in zip(*alist)]                                 
Out[362]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
In [363]: [statistics.mode(foo) for foo in zip(*alist1)]                                
....
StatisticsError: no unique mode; found 2 equally common values
```

`mode` docs warns about this error.

The `scipy` version will the list into a 2d array; which

```
In [365]: stats.mode(alist,axis=0)                                                      
Out[365]: ModeResult(mode=array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]), count=array([[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]))
In [366]: stats.mode(alist1,axis=0)                                                     
Out[366]: ModeResult(mode=array([[0, 2, 3, 4, 0]]), count=array([[1, 2, 1, 2, 1]]))
In [367]: np.array(alist1)                                                              
Out[367]: 
array([[0, 2, 3, 4, 0],
       [1, 2, 9, 4, 5]])
```

`stats.mode` code is Python, so it can be studied.  With an axis choice like this, it apparently iterates on the columns, taking a 1d mode on each.  So the speed will be comparable to the list comprehension case.  But handling of that `StatsError` case is different.

But we could handle the error case with a little utility function:

```
In [375]: def myfn(foo): 
     ...:     try: 
     ...:         return statistics.mode(foo) 
     ...:     except statistics.StatisticsError: 
     ...:         return None # or a random value 
     ...:                                                                               
In [376]: [myfn(foo) for foo in zip(*alist)]                                            
Out[376]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
In [377]: [myfn(foo) for foo in zip(*alist1)]                                           
Out[377]: [None, 2, None, 4, None]
```

The list comprehension times are favorable:

```
In [378]: timeit [myfn(foo) for foo in zip(*alist1)]                                    
73.6 µs ± 278 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [379]: timeit stats.mode(alist1,axis=0)                                              
384 µs ± 1.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```